# VB.Net BC30068: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment

Tags: vb.net

I have error in my script, i tried to fix the code, but fail.
This is my codes.

> Error Code: Me.Chars += Conversions.ToString(ChrW(num))

```
Public Sub LoadChars()
    Dim num As Integer = -32768
    Dim arg_30_0 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Do
        Me.Chars += Conversions.ToString(ChrW(num))
        num += 1
        arg_30_0 = num
        num2 = 65535
    Loop While arg_30_0 <= num2
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Me.Chars`?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is over. Because, i forget a code